# Caesar Cipher shift issue

Tags: java

I'm having an issue with properly shifting my letters. I cannot figure out how to get z to go to a if the shift is one. Any suggestions?

```
public static String encrypt(String encrypt, int shift)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(encrypt);
    StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ )
    {
        char s = encrypt.charAt(i);

                if(s >= 'A' && s <= 'Z')
                {
                    int x = s - 'A' + shift;

                    if(x < 0)
                    x = x +26;

                    x = x % 26;             
                    str2.append((char)(x + 'A'));


                }else if(s >= 'a' && s <= 'z')
                {
                    int z = s - 'a' + shift;
                    z = z % 26;
                    str2.append((char)(z + 'a'));
                }
                else
                str2.append(" ");

            }

    return str2.toString();
}
```

I was thinking that another `if()` statement could fix it, but the gap between the original character and the one that is supposed to be shifted won't be constant so I don't think that would work.

Comment: This code seems to work as long as the shift is positive... what is the problem?

Comment: I didn't give my decrypt method, even though it's the same just with a negative shift), but when I try to back it doesn't shift back properly for end characters.

Comment: It would have been clearer if you had said so when asking the question... anyway. The code that you have, `if (x < 0) x = x + 26;` will solve this problem, but it should go after `x = x % 26`. This is because if `x` is negative, `x % 26` will also be negative, so 26 can be added to make it positive. You should do the same thing for `z` in your `else if` block.

Comment: Ah, okay. Noted for the future, and thanks a lot that solved it now I just have to get the symbols to stay but I think an `else` that appends whatever symbol that is at that index to the end of the builder would do that, right?

Comment: Yep, that should work. Glad you solved it!

Comment: Another note, you don't seem to be using `str` except for in `str.length()` (which can be replaced with `encrypt.length()`), so you can remove `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("abcxyz=>" + encrypt("abcxyz", 1));
    }

    public static String encrypt(String encrypt, int shift) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(encrypt);
        StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char s = encrypt.charAt(i);

            if (s >= 'A' && s <= 'Z') {
                int x = s - 'A' + shift;

                if (x < 0)
                    x = x + 26;

                x = x % 26;
                str2.append((char) (x + 'A'));

            } else if (s >= 'a' && s <= 'z') {
                int z = s - 'a' + shift;
                z = z % 26;
                str2.append((char) (z + 'a'));
            } else
                str2.append(" ");

        }

        return str2.toString();
    }
}
```

produces:

```
abcxyz=>bcdyza
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this boundary check for `A`..`Z`, but not for lowercase letters:

```
if(x < 0)
    x = x + 26;
```

The first `else if` should be like this:

```
else if (s >= 'a' && s <= 'z') {
    int z = s - 'a' + shift;

    if (z < 0)
        z += 26;

    z = z % 26;
    str2.append((char) (z + 'a'));
```

---

(Also, `x = x + 26` can be written as `x += 26`)